# Create a MySQL VIEW that use rows information to expand table like : [number] row into the column n[number]

Tags: mysql, view

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

lottery_results (with more than 3 million records):

```
+-----+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id  | date       | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5 | n6 | n7 | n8 | n9 | n10 | n11 | n12 | n13 | n14 | n15 |
+-----+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | 2015-07-17 | 1  | 2  | 3  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12  | 13  | 17  | 19  | 23  | 25  |
|  2  | 2015-07-20 | 5  | 6  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15  | 16  | 18  | 20  | 22  | 24  |
|  3  | 2015-07-22 | 2  | 3  | 5  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 11 | 13 | 14 | 15  | 16  | 17  | 18  | 21  | 25  |
|  4  | 2015-07-24 | 3  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 12 | 13 | 14  | 18  | 21  | 22  | 24  | 25  |
|  5  | 2015-07-27 | 6  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 15 | 16 | 17  | 18  | 19  | 21  | 23  | 25  |
+-----+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want to know if is it possible and how to do it, I need to give a VIEW like this:

desired_view_lottery_results:

```
+-----+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id  | date       | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5 | n6 | n7 | n8 | n9 | n10 | n11 | n12 | n13 | n14 | n15 | n16 | n17 | n18 | n19 | n20 | n21 | n22 | n23 | n24 | n25 |
+-----+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | 2015-07-17 | 1  | 2  | 3  |NULL| 5  | 6  | 7  |NULL| 9  | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  |NULL |NULL |NULL | 17  |NULL | 19  |NULL |NULL |NULL | 23  |NULL | 25  |
|  2  | 2015-07-20 |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| 5  | 6  |NULL| 8  | 9  | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  | 14  | 15  | 16  |NULL | 18  |NULL | 20  |NULL | 22  |NULL | 24  |NULL |
|  3  | 2015-07-22 |NULL| 2  | 3  |NULL| 5  |NULL| 7  | 8  | 9  |NULL | 11  |NULL | 13  | 14  | 15  | 16  | 17  | 18  |NULL |NULL | 21  |NULL |NULL |NULL | 25  |
|  4  | 2015-07-24 |NULL|NULL| 3  |NULL| 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10  |NULL | 12  | 13  | 14  |NULL |NULL |NULL | 18  |NULL |NULL | 21  | 22  |NULL | 24  | 25  |
|  5  | 2015-07-27 |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| 6  |NULL| 8  | 9  | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  |NULL | 15  | 16  | 17  | 18  | 19  |NULL | 21  |NULL | 23  |NULL | 25  |
+-----+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I need that the view show the [number] into the position n[number].

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `CASE` for this like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c8e2a/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know max number in advance you can use `CASE WHEN` like:

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06ef8/2/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab (id INT, date DATE, n1 INT, n2 INT, n3 INT, n4 INT);

INSERT INTO tab(id, date, n1, n2, n3, n4)
VALUES (1, '2015-07-17', 1, 2, 3, 5), (2, '2015-07-20', 5  , 6  , 8 , 1);

/* CREATE VIEW my_view AS */
SELECT id,
       date,
       CASE WHEN 1 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4) THEN 1 END AS n1,
       CASE WHEN 2 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4) THEN 2 END AS n2,
       CASE WHEN 3 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4) THEN 3 END AS n3,
       CASE WHEN 4 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4) THEN 4 END AS n4,
       CASE WHEN 5 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4) THEN 5 END AS n5,
       CASE WHEN 6 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4) THEN 6 END AS n6,
       CASE WHEN 7 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4) THEN 7 END AS n7,
       CASE WHEN 8 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4) THEN 8 END AS n8,
       CASE WHEN 9 IN (n1, n2, n3, n4) THEN 9 END AS n9
       /* Add to n25 */
FROM tab
```

Comment: This is probably the best approach, but you might want to clarify that the values for the `in` operator has to include all possible positions that a specific value can be in (so they'll be different depending on value (1 can be in n1-n10, while 25 can be in n15-n25 etc).